# Adding Sharepoint Datasource to Lucidworks

Tags: sharepoint, solr, web-crawler

I'm using Lucidworks 2.1v

When i try to add a new Sharepoint datasource.

i get the following error.

> There was a problem creating that data source: Data not reachable:
>   Cannot connect to the given SharePoint Site URL with the supplied
>   Domain/Username/Password.Reason:(404)Not Found

but i can access the Sharepoint URL via browser.

Can anyone please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the steps exactly and it works fine.

http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/help/Create+a+New+SharePoint+Data+Source

please check, whether **Installing SharePoint Additional Web Services** is added properly and accessible.